# Type alias and "instance ... where"

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, typeclass

I have a type alias:

```
type MyId = UUID
```

And a data type:

```
data MyData = MyData { myId :: MyId, .... }
```

And then I create instances for `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` for `MyData`

```
instance FromJSON MyData where
  parseJSON (Object v) = ....

instance ToJSON MyData where
  toJSON (Object v) = ....
```

I wonder, why do I have the errors:

```
1) No instance for (`FromJSON MyId`) arising from a use of ‘.:’
2) No instance for (ToJSON MyId) arising from a use of ‘.=’
```

`instance FromJSON` and `ToJSON` for `UUID` are already implemented, doesn't `MyId` have them automatically? If not, how would I implement them?

```
instance FromJSON MyId where
  parseJSON (Object v) = --- ? It's already UUID for which FromJSON is implemented

instance ToJSON MyId where
  toJSON (Object v) = --- ? It's already UUID for which FromJSON is implemented
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you importing `Data.UUID.Aeson` (from the uuid-aeson package)?

This works for me:

```
import Data.UUID
import Data.UUID.Aeson
import Data.Aeson

type MyUUID = UUID

data U2 = U2 MyUUID Int

instance ToJSON U2 where
  toJSON(U2 a b) = toJSON a
```

Comment: Ok. So alias get the same instances implemented as their original types, right?

Comment: Yup - when you say `type A = B`, then A is just another name for B, and typicalness are defined on types not on their names.